# XPath to find a node whose first child node contains a certain value

Tags: html, xpath

I have to identify a certain row in a table based on the value in a certain column, specifically its first column.

This table has no id values or class values. It's just `tr's` and `td's`.

I've gotten as far as

```
//tr[td="1"]
```

but that only finds table rows for whom any tabledata in it, has text that matches the value 1, not just for the first `td` that matches 1.

I'm not sure how to address the first `td` in the `tr` and match it to a certain value. I presume once I have that, I'll be able to use something like `/ancestor::td` to just get back to the `td`

Can anyone help? Any assistance would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

In the two minutes since posting this question, I figured out this

```
//tr/td[position() = 1 and text() = "pizza 1"]
```

which gets me as far as selecting the first `td` who text value is "pizza 1" so now I just need to be able to select the tr based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first `td` that matches `1`, you can use:

```
//tr[td="1"][1]
```

Following your edit, to get the parent, you can use `..`, so:

```
//tr/td[position() = 1 and text() = "pizza 1"]/..
```

would give you the `tr` instead of the `td`.

### Update:

If you have multiple rows matching and want only the first one, you can still use `[1]`, just use it outside the whole expression (notice the `()[1]` around the whole expression):

```
(//tr/td[position() = 1 and text() = "1"]/..)[1]
```

Comment: That doesn't get it. That will get all the trs that have a td whose text is 1, and then giving me the first one. that td could be the first or the third td in that tr.

Comment: I see, I thought that was what you were after. I added a note about your edit, then.

Comment: I only have one more question. If there are two rows that match the criteria //tr/td[position() = 1 and text() = "pizza 1"]/.. I'll get two nodes, so I still need to figure out how to get the first node from that result. Putting in a [1] like //tr/td[position() = 1 and text() = "pizza 1"][1]/.. doesn't change anything in my xpath checker

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested predicate filter to look for any TR element who's first TD element contains '1'.

```
//tr[td[position() = 1 and contains(., '1')]]
```